# InvalidOperationException: Configuration 'DrugiStupanjPukId' was not found and a default value was not specified

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager

I am developing a workflow as a part of Visual Studio full trust solution. In the workflow I have used `GetConfigurationValue` activity. Configuration value is defined in appropriate `Elements.xml` file:

```
<Property Name="DrugiStupanjPukId" Value="{$ListId:Lists/DrugiStupanjPuk;}" />
```

This workflow is associated to 2 lists. On the first list this activity executes without a problem.

However, on the second list when workflow execution reaches this activity, an exception is raised:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Configuration 'DrugiStupanjPukId'
>   was not found and a default value was not specified. at
>   Microsoft.Activities.GetConfigurationValue.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem with the second list and resolved this issue, so I'm posting a solution for future reference.

Workflow association to the first list was defined in `Elements.xml` file while second workflow association was defined **programmatically** in feature receiver using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices` library. All I needed to do was to add missing configuration properties programmatically.

Setting configuration properties programmatically is done by calling `WorkflowSubscription.SetProperty` method. Complete code snippet which resolved the issue:

```
public static void AssociateWfTemplateToList(
    string siteUrl, 
    string templateWfName, 
    string newWfSubscriptionName, 
    Guid targetListGuid,
    List<string> events,
    NameValueCollection configurationProperties) {
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl)) {

        //Workflow Services Manager which will handle all the workflow interaction.
        WorkflowServicesManager wfServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext, clientContext.Web);

        //Deployment Service which holds all the Workflow Definitions deployed to the site
        WorkflowDeploymentService wfDeploymentService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();

        //Get all the definitions from the Deployment Service, or get a specific definition using the GetDefinition method.
        WorkflowDefinitionCollection wfDefinitions = wfDeploymentService.EnumerateDefinitions(false);

        clientContext.Load(wfDefinitions, wfDefs => wfDefs.Where(wfd => wfd.DisplayName == templateWfName));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        WorkflowDefinition wfDefinition = wfDefinitions.First();

        //The Subscription service is used to get all the Associations currently on the SPSite
        WorkflowSubscriptionService wfSubscriptionService = wfServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();

        //The subscription (association)
        WorkflowSubscription wfSubscription = new WorkflowSubscription(clientContext);
        wfSubscription.DefinitionId = wfDefinition.Id;
        wfSubscription.Enabled = true;
        wfSubscription.Name = newWfSubscriptionName;

        // set the workflow start settings
        wfSubscription.EventTypes = events;

        // set the associated configuration properties
        foreach (string key in configurationProperties)
        {
            wfSubscription.SetProperty(key, configurationProperties[key]);
        }

        //Create the Association
        wfSubscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList(wfSubscription, targetListGuid);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```